# default text with css

Tags: asp.net, css

I would like to print some text with CSS. Please let me know if there is any property to do this. I know CSS is only styling but I got a requirement to do like that. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS [content](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) property may be what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [CSS 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html) - the generated content section.

You are looking for the [`content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) property.

> This property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements to generate content in a document.

And:

> The following rule causes the string "Chapter: " to be generated before each H1 element:

```
H1:before { 
  content: "Chapter: ";
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: if I want to specify acts inline css..i mean using sytle attribute..thanks !